# Google Site Perfomance and javascript

Tags: google-search-console

Google Webmaster tools has lab feature named "Site Perfomance".

I've read about it in google help but it's unclear whether page loading time includes javascript execution or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does. It is meant to be a measure of site performance as experienced by the user. Hence, anything that blocks or slows down page load is factored in.

In general, the most significant metric is "document complete". Scripts block document complete unless they are deferred to after that event. It is considered good form to load third party scripts after your page content if possible.

Moreover, it's appropriate to load your own scripts after the main page body, either at the end of the document or after document complete as well.

in JQuery, you'd achieve this using the window.load function:

```
   $(window).load(function() {
      // load your scripts here
   }
```